# Include classes in a maven jar package properly

Tags: java, maven, include, maven-jar-plugin

My target directory has main sub-folders and I don't want those sub-folders be included in my package, only their contents (folders and files they consist of).

For example, this is my target folder:

> targetFolder
>   -subfolder1
>   -subfolder2

Currently, I am using Maven-Jar-Plugin but I don't know how I will be able to package my jar as structured below.

> from *subfolder1*, include only **base/**/*files1.*** 
>  from
>   *subfolder2*, include only **base/**/*files2.***

For that one, i tried doing this but it did not result to a jar structure that I want.

```
<include>subfolder1/base/**/*files1.*</include>
<include>subfolder2/base/**/*files2.*</include>
```

*This is considering that both folders have similar structure*

By doing so, the result jar when opened would look like:

> subfolder1
>   - -base
>   - - -sub1
>   - - - -sub2
>   - - - - -sub3
>   - - - - - -subfolder1files1.class
>   subfolder2
>   - -base
>   - - -sub1
>   - - - -sub2
>   - - - - -sub3
>   - - - - - -subfolder2files2.class

I want my jar package to look like this:

> base
>   -sub1
>   - -sub2
>   - - -sub3
>   - - - -subfolder1files1.class
>   - - - -subfolder2files2.class

This is just an example but I hope I have shown the situation of my target folder where I have plenty sub-folders and I have filters to include in the jar package for each of the target sub-folders.

Comment: Are those sub folders java packages? If yes it does not make sense to only include their content cause a package is an identification where to find a class...I assume you have those folders under `src/main/java/...`? Or do you have them under `src/main/resources/...`?

Comment: contents are from a target folder which was generated after the java files are compiled. @khmarbaise

Comment: And why do you need to change the structure of a resulting jar file? What is the purpose of that?

Comment: some parts of the package are only generated. They were not physically in my src/main, just generated. Also, in my actual project, there needs to be a number of jars that i need to create in one module which has their own contents. @khmarbaise

Comment: This means you should create a saparate maven module which contains the generated code and another which contains the manually created parts...

Comment: Why did you delete this question only to repost it? I'm pretty sure I have seen this exact same question, and commented on it... And the question is still a bit unclear but having 2 modules sounds like your real solution here.

Comment: @Tunaki, i don't know haha i was thinking my post will get noticed again when i repost it. Haha